# Laravel How to get web or auth middleware to work

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

Developing a Laravel packages and in the routes I have this routes

```
Route::middleware(['web'])->group(function () {
Route::get('/pckOne', 'Frutdev\LaravPck\Controllers\PckController@getIndex');

Route::get('/pckZone', 'Frutdev\LaravPck\Controllers\PckController@getZone');
Route::post('/pckZone', 'Frutdev\LaravPck\Controllers\PckController@postZone');
Route::get('/pckUsers', 'Frutdev\LaravPck\Controllers\PckController@getUsers');
Route::get('/pckUser', 'Frutdev\LaravPck\Controllers\PckController@getCurrentUser');
Route::get('/pckArea', 'Frutdev\LaravPck\Controllers\PckController@getArea');
Route::post('/pckArea', 'Frutdev\LaravPck\Controllers\PckController@postArea');
Route::get('/{Area}/pckZones', 'Frutdev\LaravPck\Controllers\PckController@getAreaZones');
Route::post('/{Area}/pckZone', 'Frutdev\LaravPck\Controllers\PckController@postAreaZone');
});
```

The routes are not being authenticated.

I tried with the web middleware but can still see/access the routes while not logged in.

I tried with the auth middleware but even after logging in with the default Laravel loggin in system(which wasn't altered) I can't access the routes. It says I'm unauthorized, even after logging in. Any idea?

`GET /login` whenever I try to go with the auth middleware to `/pckOne` returns a `302 Found` status.

Comment: Last time I used Laravel, the middleware for authentication was called `auth` not `web`!

Answer (score 2):

To have the auth middleware functional you need something like the following:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

            // Home Controller After Logging In
            Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
        });
```

This means it will check auth before running the GET route. If you're signed in then great it'll run, if not your middleware will throw the sufficient redirect back to the login page as an example.

Comment: I just tried it and I can't access /home with it. I put it in the default ```routes/web.php``` and disables the whole thing.

Comment: Did you modify your middleware for auth after adding it into the routes?